# Zend Framework render view of another controller

Tags: zend-framework

Is it possible to render view of another controller?

Because when i'm trying to pass path to render method it can't find it, but the path is displayed properly.

Is this were done for some security reason or i'm just doing it wrong way?

I'm trying to render view template of Index controller view/scripts/index/index.phtml from different controller action.

```
Message: script 'banner/c-xampp-xampp-htdocs-chat-application-settings/-/-/application/views/scripts/index/index.phtml' not found in path (C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\chat\application\settings/../../application/views\scripts/)
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can simply do this in the action:

```
$this->renderScript('index/index.phtml');
```